# JavaScript: If only working for first statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Ok the problem is that only the SHIFT key is working??? Its the first IF on the list so for some reason it isn't going to the other ones??? Help Please :)

UPDATE: Someone has suggested it's the "else if" causing the issue. I have tried it the other way. I have tried it ***every way*** that I can think of. Please just post a working example. Thanks.

Also... If someone can tell me why the key code isn't displaying that would be awesome :)

KeypressCapture.js

```
//START Screen_Keypress_Capture
function Screen_Keypress_Capture () {
    document.onkeydown = KeyDown_Handler;
    document.onkeyup = KeyUp_Handler;
    var CTRL_Key = false;         
    var SHIFT_Key = false;        
    var ALT_Key = false;
    var JavaScript_Key_Code = -1;

function KeyDown_Handler(ThisEvent) { // (e) is short for event: You can use any name you like (ThisEvent)
                                        // It's a way of passing the same event from one function to another
                                        // START Key-Down Handler
    var Key_Pressed = '';
    if (document.all)
    {
        var Window_Event = window.event;
        Key_Pressed =  Window_Event.keyCode;
    }
    else
    {
        Key_Pressed = ThisEvent.keyCode;
    }
    Detect_Keys_Pressed(Key_Pressed, true);
    Show_Keys_Pressed();
}// END Key-Down Handler

function KeyUp_Handler(ThisEvent) { // START Key-Up Handler
    var Key_Pressed = '';
    if (document.all)
    {
        var Window_Event = window.event;
        Key_Pressed = Window_Event.keyCode;
    }
    else
    {
        Key_Pressed = ThisEvent.keyCode;
    }
    Detect_Keys_Pressed(Key_Pressed, false);
    Show_Keys_Pressed();
}// END Key-Up Handler

function Detect_Keys_Pressed(Key_Pressed, Is_Key_Still_Down) { // START Detect Which Key Is Pressed
    if (Key_Pressed == '16')
    {
        SHIFT_Key = Is_Key_Still_Down;
    }
    else if (Key_Pressed == '17')
    {
        CTRL_Key = Is_Key_Still_Down;
    }
    else if (Key_Pressed == '18')
    {
        ALT_Key = Is_Key_Still_Down;
    }
    else
    {
        if(Is_Key_Still_Down)
            JavaScript_Key_Code = Key_Pressed;
        else
            JavaScript_Key_Code = -1;
    }   
}// END Detect Which Key Is Pressed

function Show_Keys_Pressed() { // START Show Results IN DIV's
// Example to move a div
// var dest = document.getElementById("my_div");
// var orig = document.getElementById("ad_div");
// orig.parentNode.removeChild(orig);
// dest.appendChild(orig);
    var Show_Current_Keys_Pressed = document.getElementById('Show_Current_Keys_Pressed');
    var DIV_Shift = document.getElementById('DIV_Shift');
    var DIV_Ctrl = document.getElementById('DIV_Ctrl');
    var DIV_Alt = document.getElementById('DIV_Alt');
    var DIV_Char = document.getElementById('DIV_Char');

    if(SHIFT_Key == true){
        DIV_Shift.parentNode.removeChild(DIV_Shift);
        Show_Current_Keys_Pressed.appendChild(DIV_Shift);
        DIV_Shift.style.visibility = "visible";
    }

    else if(SHIFT_Key == false){
        DIV_Shift.style.visibility = "hidden";
        Show_Current_Keys_Pressed.parentNode.removeChild(DIV_Shift);
        body.appendChild(DIV_Shift);    
    }

    else if(CTRL_Key == true){
        DIV_Ctrl.parentNode.removeChild(DIV_Ctrl);
        Show_Current_Keys_Pressed.appendChild(DIV_Ctrl);
        DIV_Ctrl.style.visibility = "visible";
    }

    else if(CTRL_Key == false){
        DIV_Ctrl.style.visibility = "hidden";
        Show_Current_Keys_Pressed.parentNode.removeChild(DIV_Ctrl);
        body.appendChild(DIVCtrl);
    }

    else if(ALT_Key == true){
        DIV_Alt.parentNode.removeChild(DIV_Alt);
        Show_Current_Keys_Pressed.appendChild(DIV_Alt);
        DIV_Alt.style.visibility = "visible";
    }

    else if(CTRL_Key == false){
        DIV_Alt.style.visibility = "hidden";
        Show_Current_Keys_Pressed.parentNode.removeChild(DIV_Alt);
        body.appendChild(DIV_Alt);
    }

    else if(JavaScript_Key_Code == true){
        DIV_Char.parentNode.removeChild(DIV_Char);
        Show_Current_Keys_Pressed.appendChild(DIV_Char);
        DIV_Char.innerHTML = JavaScript_Key_Code;   
        DIV_Char.style.visibility = "visible";
    }

    else if(JavaScript_Key_Code == false){
        DIV_Char.style.visibility = "hidden";
        DIV_Char.innerHTML = JavaScript_Key_Code;   
        Show_Current_Keys_Pressed.parentNode.removeChild(DIV_Char);
        body.appendChild(DIV_Char);
    }

    else{}

}// END Show Results IN DIV's

}
// END Screen_Keypress_Capture
```

KeypressCapture.css

Include CSS: href="KeypressCapture.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"

Include JavaScript: src="KeypressCapture.js"

```
    #Show_Current_Keys_Pressed {
    width: 400px;
    height: 21px;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 30px; /* UP RIGHT DOWN LEFT */
    margin: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    -webkit--moz-border-radius:4px;
    background-color: #fff;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
}

#Show_Current_Combo {
    width: 400px;
    height: 21px;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 30px; /* UP RIGHT DOWN LEFT */
    margin: 40px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    -webkit--moz-border-radius:4px;
    background-color: #FCFFA8;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
}

#Show_Created_String {
    width: 400px;
    height: 21px;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 30px; /* UP RIGHT DOWN LEFT */
    margin: 40px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    -webkit--moz-border-radius:4px;
    background-color: #FFE2C6;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
}

#DIV_Shift {
    font: Arial, Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
    visibility: hidden;
    float: left;
}

#DIV_Ctrl {
    font: Arial, Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: green; 
    visibility: hidden;
    float: left;
}

#DIV_Alt {
    font: Arial, Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: blue; 
    visibility: hidden;
    float: left;
}

#DIV_Char {
    font: Arial, Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black; 
    visibility: hidden;
    float: left;

}

.STYLE_Shift {
    font: Arial, Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red; 
    visibility: hidden;
    float: left;
}

.STYLE_Ctrl {
    font: Arial, Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: green; 
    visibility: hidden;
    float: left;
}

.STYLE_Alt {
    font: Arial, Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: blue; 
    visibility: hidden;
    float: left;
}

.STYLE_Char {
    font: Arial, Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black; 
    visibility: hidden;
    float: left;
}
```

KeypressCapture..html

```
<div id="Show_Current_Keys_Pressed">
</div>

<div id="Show_Current_Combo">
</div>

<div id="Show_Created_String">
</div>


<div id="DIV_Shift">
SHIFT
</div>

<div id="DIV_Ctrl">
CTRL
</div>

<div id="DIV_Alt">
ALT
</div>

<div id="DIV_Char">
</div>
```

UPDATE: even if you use the following code it still only runs the first on the list, which is the "SHIFT" key and skips the others.

```
        if(SHIFT_Key){
            DIV_Shift.parentNode.removeChild(DIV_Shift);
            Show_Current_Keys_Pressed.appendChild(DIV_Shift);
            DIV_Shift.style.visibility = "visible";
        }else{          
            DIV_Shift.style.visibility = "hidden";
            Show_Current_Keys_Pressed.parentNode.removeChild(DIV_Shift);
            body.appendChild(DIV_Shift);            
        }

        if(CTRL_Key){
            DIV_Ctrl.parentNode.removeChild(DIV_Ctrl);
            Show_Current_Keys_Pressed.appendChild(DIV_Ctrl);
            DIV_Ctrl.style.visibility = "visible";
        }else{ 
            DIV_Ctrl.style.visibility = "hidden";
            Show_Current_Keys_Pressed.parentNode.removeChild(DIV_Ctrl);
            body.appendChild(DIVCtrl);
        }

        if(ALT_Key){
            DIV_Alt.parentNode.removeChild(DIV_Alt);
            Show_Current_Keys_Pressed.appendChild(DIV_Alt);
            DIV_Alt.style.visibility = "visible";
        }else{ 
            DIV_Alt.style.visibility = "hidden";
            Show_Current_Keys_Pressed.parentNode.removeChild(DIV_Alt);
            body.appendChild(DIV_Alt);
        }

        if(JavaScript_Key_Code){
            DIV_Char.parentNode.removeChild(DIV_Char);
            Show_Current_Keys_Pressed.appendChild(DIV_Char);
            DIV_Char.innerHTML = JavaScript_Key_Code;   
            DIV_Char.style.visibility = "visible";
        }else{ 
            DIV_Char.style.visibility = "hidden";
            DIV_Char.innerHTML = JavaScript_Key_Code;   
            Show_Current_Keys_Pressed.parentNode.removeChild(DIV_Char);
            body.appendChild(DIV_Char);
        }
```

Comment: _The first if_? Do you mean `if (document.all)`? Are you using Internet Explorer?

Comment: You may find the following useful: http://javascript.about.com/od/hintsandtips/a/worst_4.htm

Comment: You're using `else if`. So it only executes the second `if` if the first one is false. And the third `if` is only executed if the first two are both false. And so on.

Comment: Why are you using `document.all`? That's only needed for compatibility with IE4 -- prehistoric.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your use of `else if`. It only executes that block if all the preceding blocks are false. But your code looks like this:

```
if(SHIFT_Key == true){
    ...
}
else if(SHIFT_Key == false){
    ...  
}
else if(CTRL_Key == true){
    ...
}
```

If the first `if` fails, the second one is guaranteed to succeed (`SHIFT_Key` is either `true` or `false`). So the next `else` will never be used.

You should test each key separately, without `else if`.

Next problem: `JavaScript_Key_Code` isn't true/false; it's set to `-1` when no key is pressed, or the key code while the key is down. So you should compare it with `-1`.

Next problem: You have `body.appendChild(DIV_Shift);` in your `else` clauses, but there's no variable `body`, it's `document.body`.

Next problem: You have a typo, `DIVCtrl` should be `DIV_Ctrl`.

Next problem: Each of your `else` blocks does something like `Show_Current_Keys_Pressed.parentNode.removeChild(DIV_Shift);`. But after the first time you pressed a different key, this DIV is no longer a child of that parent node, it was relocated to the body. This error causes the function to stop. You need to test whether it's currently in that node before moving it.

```js
//START Screen_Keypress_Capture
function Screen_Keypress_Capture() {
    document.onkeydown = KeyDown_Handler;
    document.onkeyup = KeyUp_Handler;
    var CTRL_Key = false;
    var SHIFT_Key = false;
    var ALT_Key = false;
    var JavaScript_Key_Code = -1;

    function KeyDown_Handler(ThisEvent) { // (e) is short for event: You can use any name you like (ThisEvent)
        // It's a way of passing the same event from one function to another
        // START Key-Down Handler
        var Key_Pressed = '';
        if (document.all) {
            var Window_Event = window.event;
            Key_Pressed = Window_Event.keyCode;
        } else {
            Key_Pressed = ThisEvent.keyCode;
        }
        Detect_Keys_Pressed(Key_Pressed, true);
        Show_Keys_Pressed();
    } // END Key-Down Handler

    function KeyUp_Handler(ThisEvent) { // START Key-Up Handler
        var Key_Pressed = '';
        if (document.all) {
            var Window_Event = window.event;
            Key_Pressed = Window_Event.keyCode;
        } else {
            Key_Pressed = ThisEvent.keyCode;
        }
        Detect_Keys_Pressed(Key_Pressed, false);
        Show_Keys_Pressed();
    } // END Key-Up Handler

    function Detect_Keys_Pressed(Key_Pressed, Is_Key_Still_Down) { // START Detect Which Key Is Pressed
        if (Key_Pressed == '16') {
            SHIFT_Key = Is_Key_Still_Down;
        } else if (Key_Pressed == '17') {
            CTRL_Key = Is_Key_Still_Down;
        } else if (Key_Pressed == '18') {
            ALT_Key = Is_Key_Still_Down;
        } else {
            if (Is_Key_Still_Down) JavaScript_Key_Code = Key_Pressed;
            else JavaScript_Key_Code = -1;
        }
    } // END Detect Which Key Is Pressed

    function Show_Keys_Pressed() { // START Show Results IN DIV's
        // Example to move a div
        // var dest = document.getElementById("my_div");
        // var orig = document.getElementById("ad_div");
        // orig.parentNode.removeChild(orig);
        // dest.appendChild(orig);
        var Show_Current_Keys_Pressed = document.getElementById('Show_Current_Keys_Pressed');
        var DIV_Shift = document.getElementById('DIV_Shift');
        var DIV_Ctrl = document.getElementById('DIV_Ctrl');
        var DIV_Alt = document.getElementById('DIV_Alt');
        var DIV_Char = document.getElementById('DIV_Char');
        var body = document.body;

        if (SHIFT_Key == true) {
            DIV_Shift.parentNode.removeChild(DIV_Shift);
            Show_Current_Keys_Pressed.appendChild(DIV_Shift);
            DIV_Shift.style.visibility = "visible";
        } else {
            if (DIV_Shift.parentNode != body) {
                DIV_Shift.style.visibility = "hidden";
                Show_Current_Keys_Pressed.parentNode.removeChild(DIV_Shift);
                body.appendChild(DIV_Shift);
            }
        }

        if (CTRL_Key == true) {
            DIV_Ctrl.parentNode.removeChild(DIV_Ctrl);
            Show_Current_Keys_Pressed.appendChild(DIV_Ctrl);
            DIV_Ctrl.style.visibility = "visible";
        } else {
            if (DIV_Ctrl.parentNode != body) {
                DIV_Ctrl.style.visibility = "hidden";
                Show_Current_Keys_Pressed.parentNode.removeChild(DIV_Ctrl);
                body.appendChild(DIV_Ctrl);
            }
        }

        if (ALT_Key == true) {
            DIV_Alt.parentNode.removeChild(DIV_Alt);
            Show_Current_Keys_Pressed.appendChild(DIV_Alt);
            DIV_Alt.style.visibility = "visible";
        } else {
            if (DIV_Alt.parentNode != body) {
                DIV_Alt.style.visibility = "hidden";
                Show_Current_Keys_Pressed.parentNode.removeChild(DIV_Alt);
                body.appendChild(DIV_Alt);
            }
        }

        if (JavaScript_Key_Code != -1) {
            DIV_Char.parentNode.removeChild(DIV_Char);
            Show_Current_Keys_Pressed.appendChild(DIV_Char);
            DIV_Char.innerHTML = JavaScript_Key_Code;
            DIV_Char.style.visibility = "visible";
        } else {
            if (DIV_Char.parentNode != body) {
                DIV_Char.style.visibility = "hidden";
                DIV_Char.innerHTML = JavaScript_Key_Code;
                Show_Current_Keys_Pressed.parentNode.removeChild(DIV_Char);
            }
            body.appendChild(DIV_Char);
        }

    } // END Show Results IN DIV's

}
// END Screen_Keypress_Capture
Screen_Keypress_Capture();
```

```css
#Show_Current_Keys_Pressed {
    width: 400px;
    height: 21px;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 30px;
    /* UP RIGHT DOWN LEFT */
    margin: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    -webkit--moz-border-radius:4px;
    background-color: #fff;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
}
#Show_Current_Combo {
    width: 400px;
    height: 21px;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 30px;
    /* UP RIGHT DOWN LEFT */
    margin: 40px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    -webkit--moz-border-radius:4px;
    background-color: #FCFFA8;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
}
#Show_Created_String {
    width: 400px;
    height: 21px;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 30px;
    /* UP RIGHT DOWN LEFT */
    margin: 40px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    -webkit--moz-border-radius:4px;
    background-color: #FFE2C6;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
}
#DIV_Shift {
    font: Arial, Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
    visibility: hidden;
    float: left;
}
#DIV_Ctrl {
    font: Arial, Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: green;
    visibility: hidden;
    float: left;
}
#DIV_Alt {
    font: Arial, Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: blue;
    visibility: hidden;
    float: left;
}
#DIV_Char {
    font: Arial, Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
    visibility: hidden;
    float: left;
}
.STYLE_Shift {
    font: Arial, Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
    visibility: hidden;
    float: left;
}
.STYLE_Ctrl {
    font: Arial, Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: green;
    visibility: hidden;
    float: left;
}
.STYLE_Alt {
    font: Arial, Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: blue;
    visibility: hidden;
    float: left;
}
.STYLE_Char {
    font: Arial, Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
    visibility: hidden;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="Show_Current_Keys_Pressed"></div>
<div id="Show_Current_Combo"></div>
<div id="Show_Created_String"></div>
<div id="DIV_Shift">SHIFT</div>
<div id="DIV_Ctrl">CTRL</div>
<div id="DIV_Alt">ALT</div>
<div id="DIV_Char"></div>
```

Comment: I changed it and it still only executes the first statement, which is the SHIFT key. I also have tried that previously.

Comment: Can you make a stack snippet or jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Why are you testing if `JavaScript_Key_Code == true`? When the user presses a key, you set that variable to the key code, not `true`.

Comment: Changed that last test to `if (JavaScript_Key_Code != -1)`. Try that.

Comment: `JavaScript_Key_Code` is not in a true or false state. It's `-1` or a key code.

Comment: Check your Javascript console. It's getting an error when it does `body.appendChild(DIV_Shift);` in the `else` clause because there's no variable `body`.

Comment: Even if "JavaScript_Key_Code" is not in a "true" or "false" state. It's "-1" or a "key code"., that still doesn't explain why it stops after SHIFT and does not show CTRL or ALT. but technically  "JavaScript_Key_Code" starts as -1 at the beginning of the script, gets changed to "Key_Pressed" unless no key is pressed, then it stays "-1".

Comment: I'm getting lots of other errors in the Javascript console, don't you see them too?

Comment: I am using Dreamweaver CC 2014 and WAMP server running it locally testing in IE Firefox and Chrome.. You cannot use it on JSFiddle

Comment: It runs in my jsfiddle and the stack snippet I copied here.

Comment: Ok well why aren't the CTRL or ALT keys also showing?

Comment: Most of the problems were reported in the Chrome Javascript console.

Comment: Let me apologize. I had to refresh the jsfiddle. Works great now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I personally use this. It's easy and robust.

```js
// The keys.
var KEYS = { BACKSPACE: 8, TAB: 9, ENTER: 13, SHIFT: 16, CTRL: 17, ALT: 18, PAUSE: 19, CAPS_LOCK: 20, ESCAPE: 27, SPACE: 32, PAGE_UP: 33, PAGE_DOWN: 34, END: 35, HOME: 36, LEFT_ARROW: 37, UP_ARROW: 38, RIGHT_ARROW: 39, DOWN_ARROW: 40, INSERT: 45, DELETE: 46, KEY_0: 48, KEY_1: 49, KEY_2: 50, KEY_3: 51, KEY_4: 52, KEY_5: 53, KEY_6: 54, KEY_7: 55, KEY_8: 56, KEY_9: 57, KEY_A: 65, KEY_B: 66, KEY_C: 67, KEY_D: 68, KEY_E: 69, KEY_F: 70, KEY_G: 71, KEY_H: 72, KEY_I: 73, KEY_J: 74, KEY_K: 75, KEY_L: 76, KEY_M: 77, KEY_N: 78, KEY_O: 79, KEY_P: 80, KEY_Q: 81, KEY_R: 82, KEY_S: 83, KEY_T: 84, KEY_U: 85, KEY_V: 86, KEY_W: 87, KEY_X: 88, KEY_Y: 89, KEY_Z: 90, LEFT_META: 91, RIGHT_META: 92, SELECT: 93, NUMPAD_0: 96, NUMPAD_1: 97, NUMPAD_2: 98, NUMPAD_3: 99, NUMPAD_4: 100, NUMPAD_5: 101, NUMPAD_6: 102, NUMPAD_7: 103, NUMPAD_8: 104, NUMPAD_9: 105, MULTIPLY: 106, ADD: 107, SUBTRACT: 109, DECIMAL: 110, DIVIDE: 111, F1: 112, F2: 113, F3: 114, F4: 115, F5: 116, F6: 117, F7: 118, F8: 119, F9: 120, F10: 121, F11: 122, F12: 123, NUM_LOCK: 144, SCROLL_LOCK: 145, SEMICOLON: 186, EQUALS: 187, COMMA: 188, DASH: 189, PERIOD: 190, FORWARD_SLASH: 191, GRAVE_ACCENT: 192, OPEN_BRACKET: 219, BACK_SLASH: 220, CLOSE_BRACKET: 221, SINGLE_QUOTE: 222 };
// Array to track which keys are currently pressed.
var keyDown = [];

// Keyboard state.
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
    keyDown[event.which] = true;
});

document.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
    keyDown[event.which] = false;
});


// You can now just check if say keyDown[KEYS.BACKSPACE] == true
function logger() {
    var keysPressed = [];

    for (var key in KEYS) {
        if (keyDown[KEYS[key]]) keysPressed.push(key);
    }

    document.body.textContent = keysPressed.length ? keysPressed.join(", ") : "Press keys";
}

window.setInterval(logger, 1000);
```

Comment: Works fine, you need to give focus to the snippet window though (click in it).

Comment: Also have to hold the key down long enough for the interval function to notice it. Why not just call `logger` from the event listeners?

Comment: That's not the point. The point is you can check for something like `keyDown[KEYS.BACKSPACE] == true` anywhere you need.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to say it but your approach is wrong. There are many excellent tutorials on handling key events [out](http://www.kirupa.com/html5/keyboard_events_in_javascript.htm) [there](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html). Generally it is not 100% reliable to capture single events for modifier keys like ctrl and alt. It is better to detect combinations, such as ctrl+t.

It is generally better to use events:

```
var keys = [];
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (evt) {
    keys[evt.keyCode] = true;

    // Ctrl + Shift + 5
    if (keys[17] && keys[16] && keys[53]) {
        // do something
    }
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', function (evt) {
    keys[evt.keyCode] = false;
});
```

This also makes your code more general, not having to check for each specific key for setting its state.

The key event also contains switches for the modifier keys: shiftKey, ctrlKey, altKey, metaKey. For example:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (evt) {
    console.log(evt.ctrlKey);
});
```

These switches indicate if each of the modifier keys were held down when the event fired. This is how you normally detect combinations.

As others have said, your code looks very dated. Forget about document.all. Simply obtain the keyCode from the event. Internet explorer 4 has not been around [for 15 years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_4).

Note that keyCodes are numbers, not strings. When you read the above tutorials, note the difference between keyCode, charCode, and which.

---

**Edit:** answering some of the questions below

A listener function passed to `addEventListener` always receives a single argument when it is fired - the event. You can name the argument of your function whatever you want, but this object will be the event regardless:

```
function handleClick (e)
{
    // this function will receive the event
    // the function is only called when the document is clicked
    console.log(e);
    console.log(e.target);
}

document.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
```

This event contains a bunch of useful things that you can check when the event fires - the target on which the event fired, some extra information, depending on the specific event. For keyboard events, this event encapsulates whatever the browser gathered about the state of the keyboard at that given moment (e.g. were ctrl or alt held down? [is capslock on](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html)? etc.).

There are a lot of excellent resources on the web, but another important thing is practice, practice, practice. Which you are obviously doing if you are asking questions here :)

I usually refer to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web) for documentation and tutorials. [Quirksmode](http://quirksmode.org/js/contents.html) is nice.

Also can recommend reading the source code of various projects - this can provide a lot of insight into the patterns used. Some of the [O'Reilly books](http://shop.oreilly.com/category/browse-subjects/web-development/javascript.do) might be helpful, also.

Some general reading on programming and design patterns, too.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am not a seasoned pro at programming, so when I have a task I need to figure out, I search the web and when I find something that is easiest for me to understand, I modify it. In programming books they give examples and if they don't include things then I have no way of knowing things like you just explained in an easy to understand way.

Comment: I wish there was a reference to show each part of JavaScript and what it does and how to use it (That a non rocket scientist could comprehend). and in your code, the "evt" is that something you made up or is that a reserved word? sorry if this seems like a silly question, but where would I look to figure that out and learn more?

Comment: Hey, no problem, hoping to help. Check my edited answer for more pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You have a real hack here. You have some exceptions in your code, that's why it only runs to the SHIFT part.

Try something like this without exception and for the first two keys, still ugly:

```js
if (SHIFT_Key) {
  DIV_Shift.parentNode.removeChild(DIV_Shift);
  Show_Current_Keys_Pressed.appendChild(DIV_Shift);
} else if (DIV_Shift.style.visibility == "visible") {
  Show_Current_Keys_Pressed.removeChild(DIV_Shift);
  Show_Current_Keys_Pressed.parentNode.appendChild(DIV_Shift);
}
DIV_Shift.style.visibility = SHIFT_Key ? "visible" : "hidden";

if (CTRL_Key) {
  DIV_Ctrl.parentNode.removeChild(DIV_Ctrl);
  Show_Current_Keys_Pressed.appendChild(DIV_Ctrl);
} else if (DIV_Ctrl.style.visibility == "visible") {
  Show_Current_Keys_Pressed.removeChild(DIV_Ctrl);
  Show_Current_Keys_Pressed.parentNode.appendChild(DIV_Ctrl);
}
DIV_Ctrl.style.visibility = CTRL_Key ? "visible" : "hidden";
```

Here is the full version:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #Show_Current_Keys_Pressed {
    width: 400px;
    height: 21px;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 30px; /* UP RIGHT DOWN LEFT */
    margin: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    -webkit--moz-border-radius:4px;
    background-color: #fff;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
}

#Show_Current_Combo {
    width: 400px;
    height: 21px;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 30px; /* UP RIGHT DOWN LEFT */
    margin: 40px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    -webkit--moz-border-radius:4px;
    background-color: #FCFFA8;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
}

#Show_Created_String {
    width: 400px;
    height: 21px;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 30px; /* UP RIGHT DOWN LEFT */
    margin: 40px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    -webkit--moz-border-radius:4px;
    background-color: #FFE2C6;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
}

#DIV_Shift {
    font: Arial, Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
    visibility: hidden;
    float: left;
}

#DIV_Ctrl {
    font: Arial, Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: green; 
    visibility: hidden;
    float: left;
}

#DIV_Alt {
    font: Arial, Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: blue; 
    visibility: hidden;
    float: left;
}

#DIV_Char {
    font: Arial, Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black; 
    visibility: hidden;
    float: left;

}

.STYLE_Shift {
    font: Arial, Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red; 
    visibility: hidden;
    float: left;
}

.STYLE_Ctrl {
    font: Arial, Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: green; 
    visibility: hidden;
    float: left;
}

.STYLE_Alt {
    font: Arial, Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: blue; 
    visibility: hidden;
    float: left;
}

.STYLE_Char {
    font: Arial, Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black; 
    visibility: hidden;
    float: left;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="Show_Current_Keys_Pressed">
    </div>

    <div id="Show_Current_Combo">
    </div>

    <div id="Show_Created_String">
    </div>


    <div id="DIV_Shift">
        SHIFT
    </div>

    <div id="DIV_Ctrl">
        CTRL
    </div>

    <div id="DIV_Alt">
        ALT
    </div>

    <div id="DIV_Char">
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //START Screen_Keypress_Capture
        function Screen_Keypress_Capture() {
            document.onkeydown = KeyDown_Handler;
            document.onkeyup = KeyUp_Handler;
            var CTRL_Key = false;
            var SHIFT_Key = false;
            var ALT_Key = false;
            var JavaScript_Key_Code = -1;

            function KeyDown_Handler(ThisEvent) { // (e) is short for event: You can use any name you like (ThisEvent)
                // It's a way of passing the same event from one function to another
                // START Key-Down Handler
                var Key_Pressed = '';
                if (document.all) {
                    var Window_Event = window.event;
                    Key_Pressed = Window_Event.keyCode;
                }
                else {
                    Key_Pressed = ThisEvent.keyCode;
                }
                Detect_Keys_Pressed(Key_Pressed, true);
                Show_Keys_Pressed();
            }// END Key-Down Handler

            function KeyUp_Handler(ThisEvent) { // START Key-Up Handler
                var Key_Pressed = '';
                if (document.all) {
                    var Window_Event = window.event;
                    Key_Pressed = Window_Event.keyCode;
                }
                else {
                    Key_Pressed = ThisEvent.keyCode;
                }
                Detect_Keys_Pressed(Key_Pressed, false);
                Show_Keys_Pressed();
            }// END Key-Up Handler

            function Detect_Keys_Pressed(Key_Pressed, Is_Key_Still_Down) { // START Detect Which Key Is Pressed
                if (Key_Pressed == '16') {
                    SHIFT_Key = Is_Key_Still_Down;
                }
                else if (Key_Pressed == '17') {
                    CTRL_Key = Is_Key_Still_Down;
                }
                else if (Key_Pressed == '18') {
                    ALT_Key = Is_Key_Still_Down;
                }
                else {
                    if (Is_Key_Still_Down)
                        JavaScript_Key_Code = Key_Pressed;
                    else
                        JavaScript_Key_Code = -1;
                }
            }// END Detect Which Key Is Pressed

            function Show_Keys_Pressed() { // START Show Results IN DIV's
                // Example to move a div
                // var dest = document.getElementById("my_div");
                // var orig = document.getElementById("ad_div");
                // orig.parentNode.removeChild(orig);
                // dest.appendChild(orig);
                var Show_Current_Keys_Pressed = document.getElementById('Show_Current_Keys_Pressed');
                var DIV_Shift = document.getElementById('DIV_Shift');
                var DIV_Ctrl = document.getElementById('DIV_Ctrl');
                var DIV_Alt = document.getElementById('DIV_Alt');
                var DIV_Char = document.getElementById('DIV_Char');

                if (SHIFT_Key) {
                    DIV_Shift.parentNode.removeChild(DIV_Shift);
                    Show_Current_Keys_Pressed.appendChild(DIV_Shift);
                } else if (DIV_Shift.style.visibility == "visible") {
                    Show_Current_Keys_Pressed.removeChild(DIV_Shift);
                    Show_Current_Keys_Pressed.parentNode.appendChild(DIV_Shift);
                }
                DIV_Shift.style.visibility = SHIFT_Key ? "visible" : "hidden";

                if (CTRL_Key) {
                    DIV_Ctrl.parentNode.removeChild(DIV_Ctrl);
                    Show_Current_Keys_Pressed.appendChild(DIV_Ctrl);
                } else if (DIV_Ctrl.style.visibility == "visible") {
                    Show_Current_Keys_Pressed.removeChild(DIV_Ctrl);
                    Show_Current_Keys_Pressed.parentNode.appendChild(DIV_Ctrl);
                }
                DIV_Ctrl.style.visibility = CTRL_Key ? "visible" : "hidden";

                if (ALT_Key) {
                    DIV_Alt.parentNode.removeChild(DIV_Alt);
                    Show_Current_Keys_Pressed.appendChild(DIV_Alt);
                } else if (DIV_Alt.style.visibility == "visible") {
                    Show_Current_Keys_Pressed.removeChild(DIV_Alt)
                    Show_Current_Keys_Pressed.parentNode.appendChild(DIV_Alt);
                }
                DIV_Alt.style.visibility = ALT_Key ? "visible" : "hidden";

                if (JavaScript_Key_Code) {
                    DIV_Char.parentNode.removeChild(DIV_Char);
                    Show_Current_Keys_Pressed.appendChild(DIV_Char);
                } else if (DIV_Char.style.visibility == "visible") {
                    Show_Current_Keys_Pressed.removeChild(DIV_Char)
                    Show_Current_Keys_Pressed.parentNode.appendChild(DIV_Char);
                }
                DIV_Char.innerHTML = JavaScript_Key_Code;
                DIV_Char.style.visibility = JavaScript_Key_Code > 0 ? "visible" : "hidden";

            }// END Show Results IN DIV's

        }
        // END Screen_Keypress_Capture
        Screen_Keypress_Capture();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```